# Python, как подсчитать кол-во итераций в цикле for

Tags: python

Изучаю сортировку пузырьком для списков.
Подскажите, как посчитать количество итераций в цикле for:

```
list_for_sorting = [20, -34, -42, 4, -20, -20, 29, 16, 79]

def sorting(new_list):
    last_item = len(new_list) -1
    for i in range(0, last_item):
        # print(new_list)
        for x in range(0, last_item):
            if new_list[x] > new_list[x + 1]:
                new_list[x], new_list[x + 1] = new_list[x + 1], new_list[x]

    return new_list

print('Original list: ', list_for_sorting)
new_list = sorting(list_for_sorting).copy()
print('Sorting list: ', new_list)
```

Comment: Создаете счетчик `i = 0`, внутри цикла `i += 1`, и после цикла `print(i)`

Comment: Можно создать переменную count=0. Которая внутри цикла будет увеличиваться на единицу count+=1, на каждой итерации

Comment: В каком именно? Их тут два. В каждом из них количество итераций равно ``last_item``.

Comment: подскажите, а как их суммировать, я добавил счетчик и при попытке вывести общее количества print(sum(count_name)) я получаю ошибку TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Ошибка говорит, что count_name уже число, его не надо суммировать.

Comment: В обоих циклах число итераций равно last_item, непонятно зачем тут что-то считать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

result = {"iteration_number_for_main_loop": 0}
for i in a:
    result["iteration_number_for_main_loop"] += 1
    key = "iteration_number_for_loop_with_value={}".format(i)
    value = 0
    for j in a:
        value += 1
    result[key] = value

for x, y in result.iteritems():
    print "{0}: {1}".format(x, y)
print "sum:", sum(result.values())

#iteration_number_for_loop_with_value=4: 5
#iteration_number_for_loop_with_value=5: 5
#iteration_number_for_loop_with_value=1: 5
#iteration_number_for_loop_with_value=2: 5
#iteration_number_for_loop_with_value=3: 5
#iteration_number_for_main_loop: 5
#sum: 30
```